# Restrict a user from calling the same handler twice while still waiting for a response

Tags: python, django

I'm developing a web application using  Django 1.3 and I have a handler that looks like this:

```
@transaction.commit_manually
@login_required(redirect_field_name='')
def problematic_handler(request):
    try:
        my_record = models.MyRecords.objects.get(...)
        # lots of database operations based on my_record
        my_record.delete()
        transaction.commit()
        return ...
    except:
        transaction.rollback()
        return ...
```

My problem is that the user can call problematic_handler() multiple times before the first call has even returned which will generate more database records than needed.

Unfortunately the PRG pattern does not help here : /

Is there any way that I can restrict the user from calling the handler twice while still waiting for the first call to return?
Or is it possible to generate exception during the second call of the handler? (of source assuming that the first one has not yet finished)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest that you try to do a [`QuerySet.select_for_update`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-for-update) in the transaction which should lock your retrieved `my_record` instance for the duration of the transaction. This would disable a successive call to `problematic_handler` to obtain an additional lock and a `django.db.DatabaseError` exception will be raised in the attempt, where you can devise an appropriate post-mortem procedure.

For Django versions prior 1.4, I'd suggest you try to do a [raw SQL select for update query](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/)  for the database record if your database supports it. Otherwise, you'll need to implement a lock at the application level and ymmv in case your application runs in a multiprocess context.

Comment: select_for_update is not present in Django **1.3** and it will be quite hard to be implemented by hand : /